# How can i display the posts per week in a particular month?

Tags: query-posts, archives

*I have to display the posts as the following*

**September 2010**

*Friday September 24, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 17, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 10, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 03, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

**can any one tell, how can do this?, or which function should i use?**

I have used the following function and i got all the post in current month

```
query_posts("year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month")
```

How can i show the posts per week of this month?

**is it work** `query_posts(""year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&post_date >$startDate&post_date <=$endDate")`

**Or what is another good way?**

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a condition to the `posts_where` filter in wordpress. I have an example here for only pulling posts that are from the current post's date and earlier:

Add this to functions.php

```
// filter wp_query when $dated_before is set
function dg_dated_before($where)
{
    global $wp_query, $wpdb, $dated_before;
    if (isset($dated_before)):
        $where = $where . " AND $wpdb->posts.post_date <= '". $dated_before . "' " ;
    endif;
    return $where ;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'dg_dated_before') ;
```

Use this, or similar wherever it is that you are running your query:

```
global $dated_before;
$dated_before = $post->post_date;
$queryObject = new WP_Query();
```

You'll obviously need to modify this to add the date boundaries that you need.